# Преобразовать materialized path в hierarchyid

Tags: sql, sql-server

Помогите написать запрос для преобразования поля `Path` в тип `hierarchyid`.

Таблица:

```
 +---------------+--------+
 | ID |  Number  |  Path  |
 +----+----------+--------+
 | 1  |   14     |    /   |
 | 2  |   95     | /14/95/|
 | 3  |   06     |    /   |
 | 4  |   10     | /06/10/|
 | .. |   ..     |   ..   |
 +----+----------+--------+
```

При попытке выполнить такой запрос

```
SELECT CAST([Path] AS hierarchyid).GetDescendant(NULL, NULL)
```

Получаю такое исключение

```
 Произошла ошибка .NET Framework во время выполнения определяемой 
 пользователем подпрограммы или агрегатной функции "hierarchyid": 
 Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.HierarchyIdException: 24001: метод 
 SqlHierarchyId.Parse завершился ошибкой, поскольку входная строка "/06/10/" 
 является недопустимым строковым представлением узла SqlHierarchyId.
 Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.HierarchyIdException: 
 в Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.ex_raise(Int32 major, Int32 minor, Int32 sev, 
 Int32 state, Object param1, Object param2, Object param3)
 в Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OrdPath.InitFromString(String chDottedString)
 в Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId.Parse(SqlString input).
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Странно. Проверил, `/14/95/` нормально парсится, `/06/10/` - с ошибкой 24001, зато `/6/10/` - парсится. Документация [гласит](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference#remarks): _Nodes cannot have leading zeros._

Comment: @i-one, Спасибо: В-внимательность:) Оформите, как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С запросом всё нормально, это данные не совсем корректные.

Строку можно преобразовать в тип `hierarchyid` функциями `CAST`, `CONVERT`, либо вызовом метода `Parse` типа `hierarchyid` напрямую:

```
SELECT
    CAST('/1/1/1/' as hierarchyid),
    CONVERT(hierarchyid, '/1/1/1/'),
    hierarchyid::Parse('/1/1/1/')
```

(в отличие от функций `CAST` и `CONVERT`, имя метода `Parse` чувствительно к верхнему/нижнему регистру символов).

Однако, для того чтобы строка распарсилась, она должна удовлетворять некоторым требованиям (см. [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference)), одно из которых

> Nodes cannot have leading zeros.

(у узлов не должно быть впередистоящих нулей) в исходных данных нарушено.

Строка `/06/10/` не может быть преобразована в тип `hierarchyid`. Если её исправить на `/6/10/`, то она может быть успешно преобразована.